# how to add a dictionary as a value to another dictionary in swift

Tags: json, swift

I'd like to add a dictionary to another dictionary in swift but I get the following error.
My aim is to mirror the structure of a nested object into a dictionary so that I am able to serialize it to JSON.

[image]

```
func toDictionary() -> Dictionary<String,AnyObject>{

        var dic = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>()

        println(From.Text)
        println(From.Email)

        var fromDic = ["Address":From.Email,"Text":From.Text]
        println(fromDic)

        dic.updateValue(fromDic, forKey: "From")
```

Answer (score 0):

the code you show works fine for me - the error is likely not on that line xcode shows.
xcode6 often misses the correct line and the real error is some lines below

Comment: Im using beta 2, what about you?

Comment: same -- comment out lines below it and try it again

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have declarations for `From`, `From.Email` and `From.Text`, then it appears to work fine:

[image]